# Groupby function with several criteria

Tags: python

I found a lot of information about the `groupby` function, but nothing that helps me with my problem:

I import an excel file.

Extract below:

```
Date    Customer    Pallets
01.01.2020  A   7
01.01.2020  B   3
01.01.2020  A   2
01.01.2020  C   12
02.01.2020  A   2
02.01.2020  B   9
02.01.2020  B   6
02.01.2020  A   1
02.01.2020  C   1
```

Using `groupby` gives me later this table:

```
Date    Customer    Pallets
01.01.2020  A   9
01.01.2020  B   3
01.01.2020  C   12
02.01.2020  A   3
02.01.2020  B   15
02.01.2020  C   1
```

That's all fine.

My problem is more:
How can I use 2 criteria specifying Date and Customer, that I for example *only* show the number of pallets for Customer "B" on 02.01.2020, so having result "15".

Comment: That sounds like a filter before or after the grouping…?

Comment: Not sure I understand, are you trying to filter, group, or reorder your data?

Comment: Are you asking about `pandas`' DataFrame groupby or `itertools.groupby`? Please add proper tag to your question, so users could easier find it.

Comment: basically i am trying to do a excel counterpart of "sumif". i want to sum up all pallets for a customer on a certain day. this will be later extended by other and more criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter for this after groupby:

```
df[(df['Customer']=='B')&(df['Date']=='02.01.2020')]['Pallets']
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a groupby question, but more like a filter/slicing question (you wanting to show only "B" on "02.01.2020").

```
# Make the groupby:
df_group = df.groupby(['Date', 'Customer']).sum().reset_index()

# Select only "B" on "02.01.2020"
df_group.loc[(df_group['Date'] == '02.01.2020') & (df_group['Customer'] == 'B'), 'Pallets']
```